# Custom configuration in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I'd like to be able to use the debugger in PyCharm while I'm using `manim` from [here](https://github.com/3b1b/manim). I've been running my code from the terminal in pycharm using this command

`python ./manim.py file.py classname -pl`

But to use the debugger in Pycharm I need to use its environment.

Right now the configuration is `~/path/to/manim.py` which is clearly necessary but I don't know how to lass in the remaining parameters in the menu.

If you're not familiar with PyCharm's configurations, here it is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under`Parameters` put `file.py classname -pl` makes sense now that I figured it out as with most things in life.